# Touchpad scrolling on the mac

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs from the shell (not aquamacs) on a mac laptop, however whenever I try to scroll up and down it doesn't scroll the file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've gotten trackpad scrolling to work for emacs + iTerm2 following [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710334/how-can-i-get-mouse-selection-to-work-in-emacs-and-iterm2-on-mac). For brevity, added the following configs to my `~/.emacs`:

```lisp
;; mouse integration
(require 'mouse) ;; needed for iterm2 compatibility
(xterm-mouse-mode t)
(global-set-key [mouse-4] '(lambda ()
                           (interactive)
                           (scroll-down 1)))
(global-set-key [mouse-5] '(lambda ()
                           (interactive)
                           (scroll-up 1)))
(setq mouse-sel-mode t)
(defun track-mouse (e))
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally holding down the 'shift' key will let you do this on xterm and friends. See if that works. Also try M-x xterm-mouse-mode which should also yield some functionality. Note that these will prob only scroll the cursor but that should be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried either of these solutions, but:

1. [MouseTerm](http://bitheap.org/mouseterm/) - passes mouse events to applications running in Terminal.app
2. [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) - claims to support xterm mouse events.

(I doubt there is anything to be done within emacs to make it work.)