# How can I get mouse selection to work in emacs and iTerm2 on Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, iterm

after turning on xterm-mouse-mode, any click on the in the screen returns "mouse-1 is undefined".  What should I be defining "mouse-1" as?  Is there some reason my mouse clicks are returning this event, and not others its suspecting?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I put this in my .emacs:

```
(require 'mouse)
(xterm-mouse-mode t)
(defun track-mouse (e)) 
(setq mouse-sel-mode t)
```

and that seems to do the trick, and now a mouse click in a split changes focus to the split.

Note: I am using iterm2, and I found the info here: http://groups.google.com/group/iterm2-discuss/browse_thread/thread/8e1f2ee7db26c07d/17ac15e69c554998?show_docid=17ac15e69c554998&pli=1

Comment: This did not work for me on OSX + iterm2. It gave me the error of unknown mouse-4 and mouse-5 when scrolling. The answer below, by bfroehle, did work.

Comment: Also didn't work for me -- when I click ANSI terminal escape sequences get inserted.

Answer (score 55):

For Emacs in iTerm 2, I've found that the following bit in my `~/.emacs` file works very well, providing the ability to insert the character at an arbitrary location, mark a region, and use the scroll wheel:

```
;; Enable mouse support
(unless window-system
  (require 'mouse)
  (xterm-mouse-mode t)
  (global-set-key [mouse-4] (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-down 1)))
  (global-set-key [mouse-5] (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-up 1)))
  (defun track-mouse (e))
  (setq mouse-sel-mode t)
)
```

Comment: Don't quote your lambdas: it's at best useless.

Comment: Note that this solution means selected text (via left click) gets copied to the Emacs clipboard.  To use the System clipboard instead, you need to use Option-Select (Mac) or Shift-Select (Linux).

Comment: This works for only terminal but not iterm2. In term2, i have to remove "unless window-system".

Answer (score 7):

Mac OS X's Terminal.app does not support mouse reporting. However MouseTerm is a SIMBL plugin that provides it with this feature. http://bitheap.org/mouseterm/

Install MouseTerm and put the following in your Emacs config file:

```
; enable mouse reporting for terminal emulators
(unless window-system
  (xterm-mouse-mode 1)
  (global-set-key [mouse-4] (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-down 1)))
  (global-set-key [mouse-5] (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-up 1))))
```

Comment: Is this really required?

Comment: In El Capitan that elisp just works without requiring you to install MouseTerm (or SIMBL) first.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that installing the emacs-goodies-el will provide the appropriate bindings.

Comment: seems like this is an ubuntu/debian package, how can I add this? I believe this is an mac configuration issue because even after issuing a (require 'mouse) a number of the function defined in mouse.el and not available in emacs.  Tried the emacs version available by default and from ports/homebrew...

Comment: `(require 'mouse)` is available in the base package.