# Use mouse to move cursor in terminal

Tags: readline, gnome-terminal

Suppose I write a line like this:

> find somedir -flag1 opt1  -flag2 opt2  -flag3 opt3  -flag4 opt4  -flag5 opt5  -flag6 opt6  -flag7 opt7  -flag8 opt8  -flag9 opt9  | xargs command ...

then I need to make some change to opt6, using keyboard, I need to press  to go back to the start, then  15 times to get there (off-by-one? good for me, wish I learned to count).

Or, if I know a little bit about Emacs, I'd press , enter 14, then  will bring me to the space after opt6.

Or, I could `set -o vi` then press  to start command mode then prefix the `f` or `t` or their uppercase cousin with an inaccurate count to get there. But I doubt even vimmer will do this, we use [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526) for that.

Sometimes I just don't feel like counting and my eyes hurt staring the dumb terminal. A left click would be wonderful, but mouse can only select text in the terminal. However, when running vim in terminal, we can use the mouse to move around(`set mouse=a`). If the mouse is available to vim, why it cannot be used in the terminal?

Ps: my system is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .emacs file:

```
(xterm-mouse-mode t)
```

See also:
[How can I get mouse selection to work in emacs and iTerm2 on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710334/how-can-i-get-mouse-selection-to-work-in-emacs-and-iterm2-on-mac)