# Same emacs settings: work fine on linux, error on mac

Tags: emacs

I have this error when loading emacs ( in terminal ) using mac. It seems to be some errors with the byte code when compiling:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable mouse-wheel-mode)    
byte-code("\304 ^X\305^H\306\307#\210\305^H\310\311#\210\305^H\312\311#\210\305^H\313\314#\210  \203?^@\315\316\317\n!\317^K!\317\320\nD!\317\320^KD!\317\321\nD!\317\321^KD!\257^F\"\210\305^H\322\323#\210\305^H\324\325#\210\305^H\326\323#\210\305^H\327\325#\210^H)\207"$
      (defvar ccm-map (byte-code "\304 ^X\305^H\306\307#\210\305^H\310\311#\210\305^H\312\311#\210\305^H\313\314#\210 \203?^@\315\316\317\n!\317^K!\317\320\nD!\317\320^KD!\317\321\nD!\317\321^KD!\257^F\"\210\305^H\322\323#\210\305^H\324\325#\210\305^H\326\323#\210\305^H\327\$
      require(centered-cursor-mode)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/nXqd/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1732                                                                                                                                                                    
      load-with-code-conversion("/Users/nXqd/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/nXqd/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)                                                                                                                                                                                  
      load("/Users/nXqd/.emacs.d/init" t t)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      #[0 "^H\205\262^@ \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202;^@\313\307\314\315#\203*^@\316\202;^@\313\307\314\317#\203:^@\320\nB^R\321\202;^@\316\322^S\323^A\322\211#\210^K\322=\203a^@\324\325\326\307^H\327Q!\"\323^A\322\211#\210^K\322=\203`^@^A^S\21$
      command-line()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      normal-top-level()
```

how to fix this kind of problem ?

Comment: It looks like the top lines of the error message are missing.

Comment: @legoscia thanks ! I've fixed my post with the line. I'm stupid enough to no search for that keyword. I have found my answer. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get mouse selection to work in emacs and iTerm2 on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710334/how-can-i-get-mouse-selection-to-work-in-emacs-and-iterm2-on-mac)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `centered-cursor-mode` inspects the variable `mouse-wheel-mode` without first requiring `mwheel`.  If you're running in graphical mode, this mode will be turned on automatically during startup and thus the variable is loaded, but apparently the `mwheel` library isn't loaded at all in terminal mode.

Try adding this to your `.emacs.d/init.el`, before loading `centered-cursor-mode`:

```
(require 'mwheel)
```